# Primefaces commandButton update throws error before the page loads

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

First of all I'm using:
 PrimeFaces 3.5
and JSF 2.2 (Mojarra)

I have this page:

```
 <ui:composition>
    <ui:define>
        <p:layout id="layout">
            <p:layoutUnit id="west">
                <h:form id-"form_filter">
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    <p:commandButton action="#{bean.action}" update=":layout:center:form_tabs"/>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit id="center">
                <h:form id="form_tabs">
                    <p:tabView>
                        <p:tab>
                        <p:tab>
                        <p:tab>
                    </p:tabView>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </ui:define>
 </ui:composition>
```

When the app tries to load this page, it gives the following error

```
    SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/pages/research/research.xhtml]
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: layout
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:608)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.findClientIds(ComponentUtils.java:245)
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.addIds(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:102)
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.process(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:84)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.buildAjaxRequest(CoreRenderer.java:200)
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(CommandButtonRenderer.java:75)
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(CommandButtonRenderer.java:50)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:308)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:181)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:125)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:847)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:300)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:101)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:847)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1819)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:847)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:877)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1826)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1822)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:395)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

But when I remove the update parameter from p:commandButton, it loads normally.

Any Hints?

Thanks for all and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: someClientId
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:608)
```

This exception will be thrown when the component identified by `someClientId` in the exception message (in your particular case thus `layout`) does **not** implement the [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) interface.

And, indeed, according the [`Layout` component API documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.5/org/primefaces/component/layout/Layout.html), it does not implement that interface. Just get rid of that part in the client ID selector:

```
<p:commandButton ... update=":center:form_tabs" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:commandButton action="#{bean.action}" update=":form_tabs"/>
```

Update the line. Actually `update=":layout:center:form_tabs"` is not finding the layout that's why the error occurred. You don't need to define id for layout and layoutunit. Simply form ids will work fine for update. If you want to update specific tab in your tabview the define id for tabview and tabs and update `<p:commandButton action="#{bean.action}" update=":form_tabs:tabviewid:tabid"/>`